# Parse XML without DOM parser and store values in a Map using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the below code to read the XML and extract values into a Map:

```
var responseBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Profiles count="3" xmlns="abcd.pqr.com"> <Profile id="1a-2b-3c"> <Name>John</Name> <Code>111</Code> <Type>Prof</Type> </Profile> <Profile id="4qr-M#ys8"> <Name>Jane</Name> <Code>511</Code> <Type>Prof</Type> </Profile> <Profile id="9uhj8-4thm#k"> <Name>Roma</Name> <Code>999</Code> <Type>Profile</Type> </Profile> </Profiles>';

var names = responseBody.match(/[^>]+(?=<\/Name>)/g);
console.log(names);

var regex = new RegExp(/id="([^"]*?)"/g);
var ids = responseBody.match(regex);
var idStrings = JSON. stringify(ids);
var newIds = idStrings.replace(/id=/g, ""); //to remove id=
var newIdsFinal = newIds.replace(/"/g, ""); //to remove "

var proIds = newIdsFinal.split(',');
console.log(proIds);

var mapOfPro ={};
for(var j=0;j<proIds.length;j++){
  mapOfPro [proIds[j]]= names[j];
}
console.log(mapOfPro);
```

Currently the resulting map looks some thing like this:

```
{
[\1a-2b-3c\:"John",
\4qr-M#ys8\:"Jane",
\9uhj8-4thm#k\]:"Roma"
}
```

Is there a better way to directly extract, parse and create a Map< String,String > that looks like this:

```
1a-2b-3c:John,
4qr-M#ys8:Jane,
9uhj8-4thm#k:Roma
```

Also extracting values into an Array and then converting it to a string using JSON.Stringify() seems to be tedious. Is there a cleaner way in JavaScript to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do use a parser. RegEx is NOT recommended

jQuery:

```js
const responseBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Profiles count="3" xmlns="abcd.pqr.com"> <Profile id="1a-2b-3c"> <Name>John</Name> <Code>111</Code> <Type>Prof</Type> </Profile> <Profile id="4qr-M#ys8"> <Name>Jane</Name> <Code>511</Code> <Type>Prof</Type> </Profile> <Profile id="9uhj8-4thm#k"> <Name>Roma</Name> <Code>999</Code> <Type>Profile</Type> </Profile> </Profiles>';

let newMap = {}
$(responseBody).find("Profile").each(function() {
  newMap[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).find("Name").text();
})
console.log(newMap)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Plain JS (ES6)

```js
const responseBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Profiles count="3" xmlns="abcd.pqr.com"> <Profile id="1a-2b-3c"> <Name>John</Name> <Code>111</Code> <Type>Prof</Type> </Profile> <Profile id="4qr-M#ys8"> <Name>Jane</Name> <Code>511</Code> <Type>Prof</Type> </Profile> <Profile id="9uhj8-4thm#k"> <Name>Roma</Name> <Code>999</Code> <Type>Profile</Type> </Profile> </Profiles>';

let newMap = {};
const domparser = new DOMParser();
let doc = domparser.parseFromString(responseBody, "text/xml");
[...doc.querySelectorAll("Profile")].forEach(function(prof) {
  newMap[prof.id] = prof.querySelector("Name").textContent;
})
console.log(newMap)
```

Plain JS (older)

```js
const responseBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Profiles count="3" xmlns="abcd.pqr.com"> <Profile id="1a-2b-3c"> <Name>John</Name> <Code>111</Code> <Type>Prof</Type> </Profile> <Profile id="4qr-M#ys8"> <Name>Jane</Name> <Code>511</Code> <Type>Prof</Type> </Profile> <Profile id="9uhj8-4thm#k"> <Name>Roma</Name> <Code>999</Code> <Type>Profile</Type> </Profile> </Profiles>';

var newMap = {};
var domparser = new DOMParser();
var doc = domparser.parseFromString(responseBody, "text/xml");
var profiles = doc.querySelectorAll("Profile")
for (var i=0;i<profiles.length;i++) {
  var prof = profiles[i]
  newMap[prof.id] = prof.firstElementChild.textContent;
}
console.log(newMap)
```

Split: (No recommended)

```js
var responseBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Profiles count="3" xmlns="abcd.pqr.com"> <Profile id="1a-2b-3c"> <Name>John</Name> <Code>111</Code> <Type>Prof</Type> </Profile> <Profile id="4qr-M#ys8"> <Name>Jane</Name> <Code>511</Code> <Type>Prof</Type> </Profile> <Profile id="9uhj8-4thm#k"> <Name>Roma</Name> <Code>999</Code> <Type>Profile</Type> </Profile> </Profiles>';


var profiles = responseBody.split('<Profile id="').slice(1)
var obj = {}
for (var i=0;i<profiles.length;i++) {
  var key = profiles[i].split('"')[0]
  obj[key] = profiles[i].split("<Name>")[1].split("</Name>")[0]
}
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: The Plain JS code snippet did not work with let and const [Guess due to old JS version maybe]
After replacing them by var, I get a syntax error at 
{code}
[...doc.querySelectorAll("Profile")].forEach(function(prof) {
  newMap[prof.id] = prof.querySelector("Name").textContent;
})
{code}

Any idea/ alternative ?

Comment: have a look now. firstElementChild should work in older browsers

Comment: Hello @mplungjan, is there any way to achieve this without using DOMParser?

Comment: Probably, the question is why? RegEx will fail spectacularly when an unexpected value is present

Comment: Why - 
Using DOMParser I get error:  **ReferenceError: "DOMParser" is not defined.**
So I am unsure if it is supported and hence moved to working with RegExp.

Comment: Ok, see last example. Simpler than yours :)